# CodeIgniter: Multilanguage when controllers hidden

Tags: codeigniter, internationalization, routes, controllers

Please help me. My situation is when I hide the index.php and controllers name on url like this:

localhost/ctc/index.php/controllers/function/ ==> localhost/ctc/function

It work fine and after that, I want multilanguage in my site and use tutorial from this site: http://maestric.com/doc/php/codeigniter_i18n, my url turn to:

localhost/ctc/function ==> localhost/ctc/en/function or localhost/ctc/fr/function

Problem is, when I change language from france to english, the current page turn to english (of course), but when I click to other pages, language come back to default language is france and I can't figure out why.

This is my routes.php:

```
    $route['default_controller'] = "main/main_page";
    $route['en/main/(:any)'] = "main/$1";
    $route['fr/main/(:any)'] = "main/$1";
    $route['en/(:any)'] = "main/$1";
    $route['fr/(:any)'] = "main/$1";
    $route['(:any)'] = "main/$1";
    $route['^(en|fr)/(.+)$'] = "$1";
    $route['^(en|fr)$'] = $route['default_controller'];
    $route['404_override'] = '';
```

Comment: are u creating links using the current URI? for example when u generate links are u taking the language change into consideration and changing the links accordingly?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how to use session in this situation and I don't take the language change into links, too. Thanks for your help...

Comment: when u create the links on the page what does the code look like?
`<a href="<?php echo site_url("main/main_page/"); ?>">Link 1</a>`

Comment: When I mouseover the link it is localhost/ctc/function. And when I clicked the core auto add language code before function like this: localhost/ctc/en/function

Comment: if it is sending u back to the default language it most likely because of incorrectly formed URL's that are being generated on your pages. If you could show me the code that generates the links on the pages then i might be able to help you further.

Comment: Sorry for my late and thoudsandly thanks to you. I solved that problem. I'm new to IC and I use base_url to generate all of my link like this: <a url="<? echo $base_url ?>/function"></a> so it auto rewrite all the link from the base. Remove it and the link rewrite with multilanguage module as charm.

Comment: great glad i could help. good luck with ur future developments